# how refrech page in jquery and asp Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

hello i try many method to refrech my page when i remove events but no succes 
how refrech my page ??

```
          $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
            if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/home/DeleteEvent',
                    data: {'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID},
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {


                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            window.location.reload(true);
                            history.go(0);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

My controller :

```
                 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
    {
        var status = false;

        var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != null)
        {
            db.Events.Remove(v);
            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }

        GestionReservation_CRUD.GestionReservation_CRUD gestionReservation_CRUD = new GestionReservation_CRUD.GestionReservation_CRUD();
        gestionReservation_CRUD.Credentials = credentials;
        status = gestionReservation_CRUD.DeleteAllocation("" + eventID);


        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };

    }
}
```

}

i used many function but the page not refrech what the problem please

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "refresh".

Comment: Use the F12 console to see if there are any javascript errors. Also use it to debug your javascript.